# What is a good PHP library to handle file uploads?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am looking to use a PHP library for uploading pictures to a web server so that I can use something that has been tested and hopefully not have to design one myself.  Does anyone know of such a library?

Edit: I am aware that file uploads are built into PHP, I am looking for a library that may make the process simpler and safer.

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload  A slick jQuery file upload system, well maintained on github.

Comment: I'm sure jQuery-File-Upload is helpful for the client side of file uploads, but I was looking for a server-side library.  This does not fill that need.

Comment: They have server-side integration examples here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/ (including php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use [HTTP_Upload](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Upload) from PEAR. It works pretty well for our purposes (uplaoding media files into a development system and uploading arbitrary files for an educational system)

Comment: No longer maintained, and last release was in 2010.

Answer (score 5):

The cunningly name [upload class](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) is very good and has a very responsive and supportive developer. Apart from uploading, it also has built-in support for lots of common image functions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has classes for everything under the sun, including file uploads. Check out the [Zend_HTTP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) class for what you want.

Comment: There is no Zend_Http class really. Do you mean Zend_File_Transfer?

Comment: [October 2016] [Zend Validator](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-validator/) can be used to validate '$_FILES' array and files on disk.  Also offers chaining and is extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://demo.swfupload.org/applicationdemo/index.php) example of [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/), the source code is available in PHP.